# Using CASE WHEN in T-SQL select statement

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, case-when

```
    SELECT Country, EmployeeName, Name As [FullName], OutPut1, OutPut2, OutPut3, 
    (OutPut1 + OutPut2 + OutPut3) AS Total,
    CASE WHEN Name IS NULL THEN '.........' 
         WHEN Name IS NOT NULL THEN '??????'
         END) 
         AS ParentID
 FROM CTE_Report;
```

The CASE WHEN in the above statement is giving trouble with the error below. Any one know what i'm missing?

> Common table expression defined but not used..

Comment: Do you mean to use Name IS NULL instead of Name isnull? Also you have an extra ')' in there.

Comment: ok, i meant IS NULL. And after correcting isnull to IS NULL, i now get "Common table expression defined but not used."

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
you forgot '(' before case when

Comment: Ok, got it. I was missing an opening bracket "(" before the CASE key word.

Answer (score 1):

Common table expression defined but not used..

this is mean that you create CTE but do not use it,
same error as in snapshot below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Country, EmployeeName, Name As [FullName], OutPut1, OutPut2, OutPut3, 
(OutPut1 + OutPut2 + OutPut3) AS Total,
CASE WHEN Name IS NULL THEN '.........' 
     WHEN Name IS NOT NULL THEN '??????'
     END
     AS ParentID
 FROM CTE_Report;
```

Its a parenthesis problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Country,
       EmployeeName,
       Name                            AS [FullName],
       OutPut1,
       OutPut2,
       OutPut3,
       ( OutPut1 + OutPut2 + OutPut3 ) AS Total,
       CASE
         WHEN Name IS NULL THEN '.........'
         ELSE '??????'
       END                             AS ParentID
FROM   CTE_Report;
```